# How to give access to edit Default Account Team member to other roles not in the hierarchy

Tags: account-teams

I want to give access to users who have roles assigned to them and want them to edit the default team member of the other user who are not in his hierarchy.

I have also checked that user can see the Account of other user who is not in his hierarchy. However he is not able to see the default account team member related list on the user page itself.

Please help me know how we can give permission to user1 to edit the default team member of the other user2 (who is not in his hierarchy). But user 1 has ability to see the Account details of user 2. User 1 can also edit the account owned by user2 and can also see the Account team on the Account record. However user1 can not see the default account team member on the user deatil page for User2

Comment: I think, User1 should be given `Modify All` access on Account.